# Is there evidence to suggest that Supreme Leader Snoke is Darth Plagueis?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke

In Episode III, [Darth Sidious](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) explains to Anakin the power of the Dark Side to save people from death. He mentions [Darth Plagueis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis) - the Sith who discovered this. Sidious then claims he died, which seems odd, given that kind of power.

Then in Episode VII (*The Force Awakens*) we find a Sith Lord who has appeared from no where. There seems to be two loose ends that fit nicely together.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that Supreme Leader Snoke is Darth Plagueis?**

Comment: Is there any reason to even remotely suspect it was Plagueis and not any other Sith lord? (Sidious, for that matter)?

Comment: “in Episode VII we find a Sith Lord who has appeared from nowhere” — is there any evidence that Snoke is actually a Sith Lord, or even Force-sensitive? I may have missed it, but despite the obvious parallels in his presentation to that of Palpatine in the original trilogy, do we get any dialogue or actions suggesting that?

Comment: Note, D. Plagueis was murdered (in his sleep) by his apprentice D. Sidious, so it is not strange at all

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, Snoke says that he has to "complete [somebody's] training". So maybe it's not enough to say he's a sith lord, but seems enough to state that he is force sensitive. He can't refer to a Ren Knight training as he is not the "Master of Ren"

Comment: @Paul D. Waite, well he said something about finishing Kylo Training. He also wanted Kylo to take Rey to him. For training I guess.

Comment: There definitely is evidence.  Enough so that tons of videos have been made on YouTube (I've watched some before).  Since I don't want to watch them all and compile a nice answer of all the evidence I leave this to you.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=plagueis+snoke

Comment: @Rashad - could you expand that into an answer?

Comment: Snoke is referred to as "wise" at one point in the film.

Comment: @BenitoCiaro - [NOBODY has ANY midichlorians in Episode VII](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112168/976) :)

Comment: Reading between the lines of what Palpatine tells Anakin in the "operate", I got the impressen that Plagueis was *his* master and he killed him. This has been explored [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113114/did-sidious-really-kill-plagueis-in-his-sleep?lq=1).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### UPDATE #3

As of *The Last Jedi* release (12/2017), there was almost<sup>[1]</sup> ***NO additional canon information that clarified who or what Snoke was***. We see a better image of him in Episode VIII, we see details of his fashion sense, but that's about it - presumably, on purpose by Story group.

> As the intended assumption is that he's now dead by the "hand" of Kylo Ren, chances are we wouldn't be finding those details out anyway. Let The Past Die.

Personally, I'm starting to fall into CBR's point of view camp: "[**Snoke May Be Star Wars’ Greatest MacGuffin**](https://www.cbr.com/last-jedi-snoke-plot-device/)".

<sub>[1] - except for a vague thing about [Sages of Dwartii and obsidian ring from Mustafar, from Visual Dictionary](https://www.cbr.com/last-jedi-snoke-sages-dwartii-theory/). And an even vague maybe possible visual similarity between his face and outline of Prime Jedi in Visual Dictionary.</sub>

### UPDATE #2

To complement Andy Serkis, Pablo Hidalgo [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/726597973619015681) just confirmed that Snoke isn't Plagueis (or rather, that Plagueis "truly, deeply" died.

> Witka ‏@timvitkuske Apr 30
>   @pablohidalgo **Can you confirm that Snoke is NOT Plagueis? Can you confirm that Plagueis is dead?**
>
> Pablo Hidalgo @pablohidalgo
>   @timvitkuske **Plagueis was killed by his apprentice. He's dead.**

And [further in a later tweet](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/729437304192794624?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw):

> Witka ‏@timvitkuske May 8
>   @pablohidalgo my real question to put it to rest, is did Plagueis' spirit survive physical death through the dark side? @colliderjedicouncil
>
> Pablo Hidalgo @pablohidalgo
>   @timvitkuske he was said to possess the ability to keep loved ones from dying. **Not himself. His apprentice killed him**.

... and [just to be absolutely sure](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/729448383094489088?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw):

> Pablo Hidalgo ‏@pablohidalgo May 8
>   @Daniel_Outhier @Gary_Thursby @timvitkuske Sidious killed Plagueis. Ascending to master. As is the way of the Sith.
>
> Marissa Talchi @MarissaTalchi
>   @pablohidalgo @Daniel_Outhier @Gary_Thursby @timvitkusk You didn't answer the Q.  Is he actually dead or does Sidious think he's dead?
>
> Pablo Hidalgo @pablohidalgo
>   @MarissaTalchi @Daniel_Outhier @Gary_Thursby **I said Sidious killed Plagueis. He killed him. Killed. As in "to kill". Like, there was killing**
>   4:10 PM - 8 May 2016

### UPDATE #1

The actor behind Snoke (Andy Serkis) [has just stated to Entertainment Weekly](http://www.ew.com/article/2016/01/02/star-wars-force-awakens-maz-kanata-supreme-leader-snoke-exclusive) that Snoke is an **original character**

> Although there was much speculation about who Snoke might turn out to be (one popular theory was that he’d turn out to be a Sith Lord known from the prequels as Darth Plagueis) he actually turns out to be … just Snoke.
>
> Serkis said the character was aware of the events from the earlier films but was a new addition to the storyline.

Of course, he may have been mis-informed himself (ala secrets in production of OT), or misinterpreting something, or intentionally hiding the truth for Disney; so until we have independent iron-clad confirmation, this is convincing but not conclusive evidence.

---

Yes, there's **some** scant evidence. Frankly, I think the theory is false because Kylo Ren isn't a Sith (as per J.J. Abrams interview).

### There's a VERY good article here: http://newmediarockstars.com/2015/12/snoke-darth-plagueis-star-wars-force-awakens/ - which lists a lot of evidence both for and against the theory.

The evidence against contains statements from J.J. Abrams, Pablo Hidalgo and Lawrence Kasdan. Oh, and George Lucas's statement that "Chosen one bringing Balance to the Force" means that Anakin **got rid of all Sith** :)

### The evidence **for** is based on the facts that:

1. In Legends/EU canon (Darth Plagueis book) Plagueis was a Muun. Muuns are:

   - Tall
   - Thin
   - Look like this:

     [image]
2. Supreme Leader Snoke is:

   - Tall and thin.

     > But Neal Scanlan, chief of creature and droid effects, told PEOPLE, “This character is much better executed as a CGI character. That’s just a practical reality when he’s 7-foot-something tall; he’s very, very thin.” (*[source](http://makingstarwars.net/2015/12/people-magazine-confirms-snokes-height-and-weight-from-star-wars-the-force-awakens/)*)

     From Alan Dean Fosters TFA novelization, Chapter X:

     > Seated on the raised platform that was the focus of the chamber was the blue-tinted holo of Supreme Leader Snoke. **Tall and gaunt**, he was humanoid but not human.
     >   Seated in shadow, the tall, slender form **loomed over the other two men**.
   - Looks **slightly kind of** like a Muun

     [image]

     ### UPDATE: having watched the film, he does look VERY MUCH like a picture of Muun from Clone Wars cartoon in certain frames. I will post screenshots when I can get them.
   - A Spanish language magazine posted a drawing depicting several characters, Snoke among them. There, he looks VERY MUCH like a Muun from Clone Wars:

     [image]

     News site Colliders published a video confirming this story.

     *Then*, according to the article linked, LucasFilm [asked Collider to remove that picture (that looks exactly like a Muun) from their video](https://www.facebook.com/johncampea/posts/10153777723422500). Which can be interpreted as "too accurate and a spoiler", but of course also as "Not accurate" :)
3. This one isn't from the article linked ([source](http://metro.co.uk/2015/06/16/star-wars-episode-7-the-force-awakens-who-is-supreme-leader-snoke-played-by-andy-serkis-5247536/)), and of course is also at best barely remote circumstantial evidence:

   > But look back to 1983 and an interview in Prevue magazine with Return of the Jedi director Richard Marquand. In the interview he mentions having discussed the entire nine episode saga with George Lucas.
   >
   > > ‘If you follow the direction, and project into the final trilogy, you realise that you’re going to meet **the supreme intellect**, and you think **how is it possible to create a man who has such profound cunning that he can not only control Darth Vader, but the fate of Luke Skywalker? Control the destiny of the whole galaxy**? You’ll be amazed!’

   And we know from canon/EU that [Muuns are highly intelligent overall](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Muun/Legends) (and Plagueis more so than average)
4. Minor circumstantial evidence arises out of TFA novelisation by A.D.Foster:

   > “Kylo Ren, **I watched the Galactic Empire rise, and then fall**. The gullible prattle on about the triumph of truth and justice, of individualism and free will. As if such things were solid and real instead of simple subjective judgements. The historians have it all wrong. It was neither poor strategy nor arrogance that brought down the Empire. You know too well what did.”

   This means he's OLD. Older than Luke.

Comment: Full disclosure: Having seen the film AND some close-up shots, I'm abbout 80% convinced by now that based on just looks, Snoke is a Muun.

Comment: I don't know that we can take JJ Abrams at his word. After all, Benedict Cumberbatch didn't play Khan, right?

Comment: @Xantec - SPOILERS, dude! I didn't see #2 ST:POS yet!

Comment: @DVK : Interesting statement by Serkis.  Should we believe him?

Comment: @praxis it's not like he is George lucas ;)

Comment: Hamill and Fischer didn't know Luke and Leia were twins, neither of the guys that went into the making of Darth Vader knew he was Luke's father.

Comment: @Axelrod - that's a good point.

Comment: @DVK Interesting that the article doesn't actually quote Andy Serkis, so we don't really know what he said. We just know he said something to lead the writer to conclude that Snoke is not Plagueis.

Comment: I don't think he really looks like a Muun, the proportions of his face aren't nearly long enough vertically compared to the width--look at [this very clear image](http://images-cdn.moviepilot.com/images/c_fill,h_582,w_1317/t_mp_quality/vyuwvbmkngxeydwtv6ax/is-star-wars-7-s-supreme-leader-snoke-the-son-of-emperor-palpatine-785624.jpg) (and please consider adding it or another image of Snoke to your answer next to the picture of the Muun, so readers can draw their own conclusions)

Comment: Also, there is [this image](http://www.cosmicbooknews.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/673/wysiwyg_imageupload/1/snoke-concept-art-star-wars-book.jpg) from *The Art of Star Wars: The Force Awakens* showing a preliminary design for Snoke, he just looks like a human (or 'near-human' as they say of some Star Wars species) with a ruined face, not a Muun. I found that image posted on [this page](http://www.cosmicbooknews.com/content/star-wars-force-awakens-supreme-leader-snoke-art#axzz3zJ3OW25r), which also includes a tweet suggesting that the spanish mag's image of Snoke is just fan art.

Comment: Based on the latest film, you may want to add an update.

Answer (score 22):

Here is some additional evidence, which I haven't already seen discussed anywhere.

**Similar Theme Music**

If you listen to the Force Awakens soundtrack song titled "Snoke" and listen to the Revenge of Sith song titled "Palpatine's Teachings" (when Palpatine teaches Anakin about Plagueis), you will find that they are too similar to be a coincidence.

**Darth Plagueis Novel Cover**

I haven't read the Darth Plagueis novel, and it is only a Star Wars "Legend", but the front cover shows Palpatine kneeling before a gigantic Plagueis, just like in the new movie.

[image]

Comment: I would gladly upvote this if someone actually provided objective analysis of the music's similarity (fourier, or some other analysis). I keep hearing that it's simiular, but with music, that is a wee bit subjective to determine via listening only.

Answer (score 21):

Snoke seems to be missing his lower jaw, which is similar to an injury Darth Plagueis received years before the Phantom Menace when he was training Palpatine.  There is no evidence that directly proves or disproves that Snoke is Plagueis, but it certainly seems like the route they're going on.

Plagueis preferred working behind the scenes, so it would be within his character to make Palpatine think that he killed his master while just waiting for the right time to come out of the shadows.  Episode VII doesn't do anything to explain this, but I'm sincerely hoping that this is what they plan on doing in future instalments.

Comment: +1 sounds relevant, but what's the information source for Plagueis having such a jaw injury? Or that Palpatine thinks he *killed* Plagueis?

Comment: @user568458 http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Transpirator

Comment: @user568458 Palpatine says, in his 3rd person telling of the story to Anakin, that he killed Plagueis in his sleep.

Comment: @Axelrod When was that? Was that epIII?

Comment: @user568458 I believe it was, though it could have been II.

Comment: @user568458 it was epIII. Here's the scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05dT34hGRdg

Comment: @user568458 It's Legends detail, but there's a force-power to be able to project images into other people's minds (demonstrated in "I, Jedi" by Corran Horn, who convinces an entire group of people that he's managed to force-lift a boulder, but rather than actually lifting it he projected the _image of him lifting it_ onto everyone's perception) shown to be possible by Jedi. Surely this is possible for a sith (seeing as this seems to be a force-power designed for deception), meaning Plagueis could simply slink away into the darkness, everyone thinking him dead.

Answer (score 1):

The actor, Andy Serkis, who plays Snoke [states he is a entirely different, new character](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/12/star-wars-andy-serkis-supreme-leader-snoke):

> "...**It is very much a newly - introduced character...He's aware of what's gone on, in the respect that he has been around and is aware of prior events. I think it'd be fair to say he is aware of the past to a great degree...** Supreme Leader Snoke is quite an enigmatic character, and strangely vulnerable at the same time as being quite powerful. Obviously he has a huge agenda. He has suffered a lot of damage. As I said, there is a strange vulnerability to him, which belies his true agenda..."

Comment: It's considered good form to credit your sources

Answer (score 0):

From [quora](https://www.quora.com/) adding backstory to the reasoning behind the Snoke situation.

In Episode IX, we see Snoke was engineered in Palpatine's cloning facility. This used Plagueis' research.