# What is J.J. Abrams opinion of fan theory of Jar Jar as the ultimate Sith Lord?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, jar-jar-binks

There is a popular fan theory [originating on Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DarthJarJar/) covering this topic.  I have always thought Jar Jar held a more substantial role in the Star Wars universe.  His action to give Palpatine unlimited powers is too glaring to ignore.  Either George Lucas was trolling us all and Jar Jar is nothing more than a 2D comic relief or he was setting us up for a deeper, subtler interpretation of Star Wars.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://www.ew.com/article/2015/11/30/jar-jar-binks-fan-theory-jj-abrams:

J.J. Abrams likes the theory:

> “There was this unbelievably lengthy analysis, in a very seriously thought-out way, as to why it’s obviously true that he is [evil],” Abrams said. “That to me is remarkable.”

### However, according to [Stephen Witty interview](http://www.nj.com/entertainment/index.ssf/2015/12/new_j_j_abrams_onthe_star_wars_jar_jar_and_the_fans.html), that's NOT the case in the film:

> "Right, 'Jar Jar is really a Sith Lord,'" Abrams says with a grin. "**I so wish I was smart enough to come up with that one. I'm not kidding. That was on Reddit, I think, and it's this very long and brilliant theory and I commend whoever wrote it – it's crazy well thought-out**. And if you read it – well, it's a little like most conspiracy theories, where if they're well-written and well-considered, you start to get convinced."
>
> OK, but on the record, can he confirm that Jar Jar is not a Sith Lord?
>
> **"He's not," Abrams says firmly. "As far as I know."**

---

In addition, we know that J.J. Abrams is in tune with all the normal Star Wars fans and wants to kill off Jar-Jar, as he admitted to [Vanity Fair](http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2015/05/star-wars-the-force-awakens-vanity-fair-cover) :)

> ... At one point during the effects review, while watching a sequence with spaceships flying low over a desert planet, **Abrams asked to pause the scene. With a light pen, he drew a little squiggle on a sand dune**.
>
> **“I have a thought about putting Jar Jar Binks’s bones in the desert there,” he said.**
>
> Everyone laughed.
>
> Abrams laughed, too, but insisted, “**I’m serious!” He pointed out that the shot zips by in a second, if that. “Only three people will notice,” he said, “but they’ll love it**.”

---

And even further than that, if you need more proof, let's ignore the Jar-Jar part of the theory and concentrate on "Sith". As per Abrams, Snoke and Kylo are **[not Sith](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/110924/976)** (though, that may be "true from a certain point of view" and Abrams simply being vague-ish to hide the fact that [Snoke is Darth Plagueis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111028/976)).

Comment: Trust you to come up with a perfect answer to *Jar Jar is a bloody Sith Lord* :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - even better now after the edit?

Comment: Well, naturally!

Comment: Thanks for those interview references.  Unfortunately that gives credit to the argument that George Lucas created Star Wars inspite of himself and that others really put the lore that everyone knows together.  If Jar Jar and the other amendments to the franchise and prequels are to be taken at face value than George Lucas truly deserves the rancor of the fan base.  Just because you create something doesn't mean you become its God, everyone is free to take away whatever they like from the source material.

Comment: If Snoke is Darth Plagueis doesn't that make him sith and by default Kylo?

Comment: @TomB - **IF** (and that's a big and unlikely IF) he's Plagueis, then yes, he's a Sith. Kylo, not necessarily.

Comment: Sith is an ideology or philosophy with a set of rules. Count Dooku was Jedi, turned into a wealthy aristocratic, turned Sith. One's philosophy can change and there are various force sensitive beings that don't belong to either one of the mainstream Sith or Jedi groups (Bendu) and/or some have offshoots (Ordu Aspectu). So even if Snoke is Plaugueis, it doesn't mean he stuck to the Sith way and we also have The Knights of Ren to consider...