# Is there any evidence in The Force Awakens towards or against Jar-Jar being Snoke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

There was a popular fan theory [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/3qvj6w/theory_jar_jar_binks_was_a_trained_force_user/) that Jar Jar Binks was really Supreme Leader Snoke.
Was there anything in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* or any of its novelizations that would lead evidence towards either supporting or disproving this theory?

To be clear, I'm looking for evidence from the film itself, not Word-of-God answers. I don't care about specific comments from producers regarding the validity of the theory. Those can already be found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112213/what-is-j-j-abrams-opinion-of-fan-theory-of-jar-jar-as-the-ultimate-sith-lord). I'm just looking for what evidence can be found from the film itself.

Comment: Well, doesn't look much like him.

Comment: @TZHX that was a hologram and not necessarily how Snoke actually looked like.

Comment: That is true, but there's no reason to believe that it's not what he looks like.   When you look outside, and see that it's light outside, do you immediately believe that aliens are shining a spotlight on your house?

Comment: +1 because downvotes make people sad.

Comment: My theory is that Snoke is about the height of Yoda, and was a Yoda-type figure when Luke started training Jedi. My theory is much less fun than the Jar-Jar one.

Comment: -1 for arbitrarily excluding the simple, obvious, definitive evidence that "the director said he isn't."

Comment: @MikeEdenfield I'm not asking whether he is or isn't. I'm asking whether the movie shows evidence either way.

Comment: I know what you're asking and I choose to think it's not a good question; you are basically asking "I know what JJ Abrams said but I don't care, is there any *proof* in the movie?"

Comment: +1 because meesa like this question.

Comment: Unlike Jar-Jar, Snoke can speak clearly.

Answer (score 27):

### Update

Since you asked for novelization proof, in the novel *"Star Wars: Aftermath: Empire’s End"* there is this:

> Also, in this book Jar Jar Binks is alive and living in disgrace on some random planet. Probably to make sure people didn’t think he was Snoke. - [Recent Star Wars Novels, Reviewed - Science Fiction & Fantasy Community Blog](https://thesffblog.com/2017/12/recent-star-wars-novels-reviewed/)

From the actual book (*all typos are correct per the book*):

> **Mapo**: Why don't they talk to you?
> **Jar Jar**: "My no no sure...Mesa thinking it cause-o Jar Jar makin some uh-oh mistakens. *Big* mistakens. Der Gunga bosses banished me longo ago. - pg. 101

### Original

It was announced from a producer that Binks does not appear in the film, and since Snoke does, well they must not be the same person.

From [theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2015/dec/07/star-wars-producer-confirms-jar-jar-binks-will-not-appear-in-the-force-awakens)

> Jar Jar Binks, the goofy amphibious character who irritated many Star Wars fans in the 1999 film The Phantom Menace, will not appear in the new movie The Force Awakens, producer Kathleen Kennedy has confirmed.
>
> **“Jar Jar is definitely not in the movie,” she said to applause and cheers.**

---

Also, JJ Abrams goes on record that Jar Jar is neither a super villain, nor a Sith Lord.

From [NJ.com](https://www.nj.com/entertainment/index.ssf/2015/12/new_j_j_abrams_onthe_star_wars_jar_jar_and_the_fans.html)

> **No, "The Force Awakens" does not feature Jar Jar Binks as a super-villain.**
>
> "Right, 'Jar Jar is really a Sith Lord,'" Abrams says with a grin. "I so wish I was smart enough to come up with that one. I'm not kidding. That was on Reddit, I think, and it's this very long and brilliant theory and I commend whoever wrote it – it's crazy well thought-out. And if you read it – well, it's a little like most conspiracy theories, where if they're well-written and well-considered, you start to get convinced."
>
> **OK, but on the record, can he confirm that Jar Jar is not a Sith Lord?**
>
> **"He's not," Abrams says firmly. "As far as I know."**

Comment: Ah-ha. That's what Jar Jar wants you to think....

Comment: Jarjar is powerful enough in the force to mind control the director himself into saying weird stuff

Answer (score 11):

Yes, Snoke is specifically referred to as being a powerful user of The Force

> *Snoke is powerful with the dark side of the Force, and seduced Kylo
>   Ren into abandoning the Jedi path to become his apprentice* -   <sub><sup>[Starwars.com Databank: Supreme Leader Snoke](https://www.starwars.com/databank/supreme-leader-snoke)</sup></sub>

Jar Jar is specifically referred to as not being a Force-user.

> *His clumsiness was once mistaken for Force powers* - <sub><sup>[*Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1465437851)</sup></sub>

**QED. Snoke is not Jar Jar**

Comment: Sorry, -1. The whole POINT of that theory on reddit was that he was a Force user who was pretending NOT to be one (ala Palpatine) by **appearing** clumsy on purpose.

Comment: @DVK - But the reference specifically says "mistaken for Force powers", so it's canon that believing he has Force powers is a mistake, not the truth.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - If you are HIDING your true identity, that's what will be believed about you. After all, it's also canon that Vader betrayed and murdered Luke's father IYKWIM

Comment: @DVK - If he was HIDING his true identity, then his Force powers would be mistaken for clumsiness--that's the opposite of what the reference actually says. The idea that Vader betrayed and murdered Luke's father was an in-universe statement by a character, but references like *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know* are not written from the perspective of any character, but from an authoritative "voice of God" perspective.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Precisely this. The factbook is just that, a book of unassailable facts.

Answer (score 10):

### Disproving:

- Snoke is extremely tall (WoG is > [Snoke is at least 7 feet](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111028/976)), Jar-Jar is
  1.96 meters according to old SW Encyclopedia entry quoted on Wookieepedia. Unless we invite NASA to the party, it's obvious Jar-Jar is shorter (7 feet is 2.1m)
- Snoke [doesn't look anything like a Gungan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111028/976)
- Snoke is implied to be crafty and intelligent. WoG is that he's [super-intelligent](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111028/976). Show of hands everyone who thinks Jar-Jar belongs in Mensa club?
- J.J.Abrams explicitly said he [wanted to kill Jar-Jar as fanservice for the film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112213/what-is-j-j-abrams-opinion-of-fan-theory-of-jar-jar-as-the-ultimate-sith-lord/112214#112214).

### Supporting:

I'm drawing nothing from actual Ep7 media. Most of the "evidence" for that theiry lies in the Prequels - namely, it's based around the fact that he was the one who initiated the vote to let Palpatine get Emergency Powers.

Here's the deal though: If you read AotC novelization, **he was bullied into it**, by none other than Senator Bail Organa. Because that was the only way to go save Obi-Wan, Anakin and Padme on Geonosis. It was NOT Jar-Jar's idea at all.

Comment: I apologize for lack of links to details, but ALL the details are thoroughly discussed in answers on this site elsewhere. Including [here for images of Snoke](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110876/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-supreme-leader-snoke-is-darth-plagueis/111028#111028)

Comment: @Richard - shouldn't you be digging up the HUD canon references for Keen's question? The current answer isn't very satisfactory :)

Comment: Star Wars: Imperial Handbook: A Commander's Guide says that each trooper has an IFF disk in the back of their suit.

Comment: “Snoke is extremely tall (WoG is > 7 feet)” oh, there goes my theory.

Comment: @Richard - does IFF identify a trooper, or merely a binary friend or foe bit?

Comment: @DVK: you should add that bit from the novelization where Snoke talks about being older than the Old Republic. Jar-Jar is clearly not that old.

Comment: @Martha - he didn't, sorry. Just that he saw the Galactic Empire rise. So did Jar-Jar for that matter :) I posted that quote on my answer about the question asking why Kylo Ren and Hux and other leaders were too young compared to ANH